# How to add a Product option value programmatically in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1

I have a product with a custom option named as Instructions which is a textarea type and is not required.

Now suppose some one doesn't fill it. how to add this value through by program.

What i have done so far is , I have managed to update the option value through a action :

```
$options = $item->getOptions();

foreach ($options as $option) 
    { 

    switch (true) 
        {

            case (strtolower($option->getCode()) == 'info_buyrequest') :
                $unserialized = unserialize($option->getValue());
                $unserialized['options'][2] = $info_option_value;
                $option->setValue(serialize($unserialized));
                break;

                case ($option->getCode() == "option_2") :
                $option->setValue($info_option_value);
                break;
        }

    }
    $item->setOptions($options)->save(); 
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->save();
```

But I am not getting how to create a similar action which adds the option value.

Hope anyone can help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update product custom options on Cart Page?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/how-to-update-product-custom-options-on-cart-page)

Comment: "how to add this value"... to what exactly? To extant orders? To quotes?

Comment: Hello benmarks, i guess this value should go to sales_flat_quotes_item_options. This is the product custom option value, or should it go to other places as well ? sorry but i am getting little confused.

Comment: Hello Muffadal thanks for comment but it's not for updating existing value as in the link you referred, it is for adding new value.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. What you are saying/asking is how to add the field to 'info_buy_request' options, if it was not filled in by a user. If the user did not fill it in, what exactly do you want to add? The field with NULL as the value? If the field does not exist in the options, then that explicitly means it was not populated, which should be enough, should it not? WHy the need to populate it? (and again, with what?)

Comment: also, your way of iterating over the item options is not needed. You can get to the data as follows:

`$infoBuyRequest = $item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
if (is_object($infoBuyRequest)) {
            $buyRequest = new Varien_Object(unserialize($infoBuyRequest->getValue()));
}`

Now your data is in an object - $buyRequest and can be accessed/manipulated as an object

Comment: @Proxiblue : Can you please post your comment as an answer??

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing.

What you are saying/asking is how to add the field to 'info_buy_request' options, if it was not filled in by a user.

If the user did not fill it in, what exactly do you want to add? 
The field with NULL as the value? 
If the field does not exist in the options, then that explicitly means it was not populated, which should be enough, should it not? 
Why the need to populate it? (and again, with what?)

also, your way of iterating over the item options is not needed. You can get to the data as follows:

```
$infoBuyRequest = $item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest'); 
if (is_object($infoBuyRequest)) { 
    $buyRequest = new Varien_Object(unserialize($infoBuyRequest->getValue())); 
}
```

Now your data is in an object - $buyRequest and can be accessed/manipulated as an object

Comment: Hello ProxiBlue thank you for the consideration but actually i was trying to create a module which let customer to select option's values in the shopping cart even if he/she forget to select it on the product page.

Comment: I see, the cart would normally place a 'configure' link in the cart for these products.

Comment: But in any case it has to go through product page for selection of custom options and i was trying to do this at cart. by the way thanks for the code for fetching information from 'info_buyRequest' i will definitely use it in future.