# How to set default value of custom options for product ?

Tags: magento-1.7, custom-options, magento-1

I have a product with custom option of text area type. now i want to set some default text which should be use when user doesn't fill any text and this text will go to cart with product.

I have searched everywhere but not getting how to do this ?

Please help if anyone know about this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a Product option value programmatically in magento?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4197/how-to-add-a-product-option-value-programmatically-in-magento)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via observer in custom module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <!-- some config here -->
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <my_module_observer_node>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductPrepareSave</method>
                    </my_module_observer_node>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_prepare_save>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <!-- some config here-->
</config>
```

And Model/Observer.php

```
class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function catalogProductPrepareSave($observer)
    {
        /**
         * @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
         */
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        if(!$product->getSomeAttribute()){
            $product->setSomeAttribute("Some default value here");
        }
    }
}
```