# How to add product custom options on Checkout Page?

Tags: onepage-checkout, custom-options, ajax

From my catalog page customer gets directly to onepage checkout.

My simple product got options which should affect price. This what I'm trying to do:
1. show options (the selection itself) on checkout page.
2. update total when any option is selected. (as its done on product view page)

[This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/how-to-update-product-custom-options-on-cart-page) seems to be the solution using ajax, but i just cant figure out, how to set everything up. 
Friends, can anyone explain the thing to beginner?