# How to check which modules are affected by security patch SUPEE-6788

Tags: extensions, security, patches, routing, supee-6788

On October 27, 2015, Magento has released security patch SUPEE-6788. According to the [technical details](http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details), 4 APPSEC's that have been fixed require some rework in local and community modules:

- APPSEC-1034, addressing bypassing custom admin URL (disabled by default)
- APPSEC-1063, addressing possible SQL injection
- APPSEC-1057, template processing method allows access to private information
- APPSEC-1079, addressing potential exploit with custom option file type

I was wondering how to check which modules are affected by this security patch.

I came up with the following partial solution:

- APPSEC-1034: search for `<use>admin</use>` in the config.xml of all local and community modules. I think this should list all modules affected by this issue.
- APPSEC-1063: search for `addFieldToFilter('(` and `` addFieldToFilter('` `` in all PHP files of local and community modules. This is incomplete, as variables can also be used.
- APPSEC-1057: search for `{{config path=` and `{{block type=` in all PHP files of local and community modules, and filter out all elements from the whitelist. This is incomplete, as it does not contain any template variables added by admins, however.
- APPSEC-1079: no idea.

There is also a [list of extensions](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHJL6D6xm3vD349DJsDF88FBI_6PZvx_u3FioC_1-rg/htmlview) that are vulnerable for APPSEC-1034 and APPSEC-1063 compiled by [Peter Jaap Blaakmeer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/237/peter-jaap-blaakmeer)

Comment: I have no idea how to contact @PeterJaapBlaakmeer but I have an extension that needs added to the list: FreeLunchLabs ConstantContact for the admin url issue

Comment: Please wait for more information in official announcement. We are working on improving the backward incompatibility of patch.

Comment: I believe 1079 would be a `serialize` or `unserialize` in a custom option. Something like `serialize($options)` a possible example: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4198/69 Also worth checking out also: https://owasp.github.io/AppSec-Browser-Bundle/

Comment: There is no patch yet for download on https://www.magentocommerce.com/download So where do you guys get this info about **future patches and updates**? So that next time I can check before patches are released.

Comment: who came up with some of these solutions? Suddenly there's going to be a block type and variable whitelist? Upgrading Magento has always been a pain, but good job to Magento for making it even more of a pain.

Comment: Heh, Magento, the gift that keeps on giving. I just finished upgrading ALL the modules for 1.9.2.1 compatibility. Bet module developers are just jumping for joy or running screaming for the hills.

Comment: at this moment patch postponed for next week -  postpone the security patch release until early next week and modify the patch so that the admin routing changes are turned off by default.  This means that the patch will include the fix, but that it will be disabled when installed. The new release date and changes to the patch will give you some additional time to make updates to your code and will give merchants flexibility to turn on this part of the patch once their extensions and customizations have been updated to work with it.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply. BTW I think the config path whitelist in the technical details is incomplete: trans_email/ident_general/email, trans_email/ident_support/email and trans_email/ident_support/name are missing.

Comment: APPSEC-1063 will mean that code like follows does not work: `$collection->addFieldToFilter('`field`', array('eq' => 3)); `

What happens if there is an intentional need for the backtick? I know a magento instance with an attribute called `drop` which needs backticked to escape it as `drop` is a reserved mysql word.

Comment: If anyone need, we have written a small tuto on how to update your module to fix your custom admin routes: http://www.digital-pianism.com/en/blog/how-to-update-modules-before-magento-patch-supee-6788/

Comment: Is there really **no** way of addressing these vulnerabilities without such major backwards incompatibility? I feel like someone found an imperfection in the paint and used a hammer to smooth it out.

Comment: Unfortunately no:  with variables you get access to things like PayPal password or block of recent orders. And we have seen them being processed based on customer input. With admin routing, it helps stops automated large scale attacks like the recent Guruincsite.

Comment: PATCH has been released https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

Comment: @PiotrKaminski So, why a *whitelist* instead of a *blacklist*? It sounds like you've identified some blocks and variables which should not be output via `{{ templates }}`, so why not put them in a blacklist instead of introducing a breaking whitelist?

Comment: @AadMathijssen Who (and where) to contact to notify that some of modules were updated and are no compatible with SUPEE-6788?

Comment: @zitix https://github.com/peterjaap

Answer (score 55, accepted):

SUPEE-6788 released and admin routing changes turned off by default. This means that the patch include the fix, but that it will be disabled when installed. This will give you some additional time to make updates to your code and will give merchants flexibility to turn on this part of the patch once their extensions and customizations have been updated to work with it.

For enable admin routing capability for extensions after install the path go to Admin -> Advanced -> Admin -> Security.

**Magento CE 1.4-1.6** patches are delayed and should be available in about one week!

**SUPEE-6788 Resources list**

- **Official details & download SUPEE-6788** - http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788 &
  https://www.magentocommerce.com/download
- **How to apply SUPEE-6788 discussion with useful tips** - https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/734/2282
- **Install SUPEE-6788 without SSH** - https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-6788-without-ssh/
- **SUPEE-6788 for CE 1.7.0.1 - 1.9.2.1 on GitHub** - https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/tree/master/current-patches/CE
- **SUPEE-6788 for EE 1.12.x - 1.14.x on GitHub** - https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches/tree/master/current-patches/EE
- **SUPEE-6788 and Backward Compatibility** - https://info2.magento.com/rs/318-XBX-392/images/SUPEE-6788-Technical%20Details.pdf
- **Community driven up to date list of Extensions that will break with SUPEE-6788 / Magento 1.9.2.2 / EE 1.14.2.2** -
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHJL6D6xm3vD349DJsDF88FBI_6PZvx_u3FioC_1-rg/htmlview?sle=true#gid=0
- **Helpful Magerun commands** https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons

  - n98-magerun dev:template-var - Find non-whitelisted vars/blocks to be compatible with SUPEE-6788 and Magento 1.9.2.2
  - n98-magerun.phar dev:old-admin-routing - Find extensions that use old-style admin routing (which is not compatible with SUPEE-6788 and
    Magento 1.9.2.2)
- **Check if store patched / affected** - https://www.magereport.com/
- **Some of custom blocks on the front page have disappeared after patch install** - [APPSEC-1057 How to add variables or blocks to the white list tables](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87466/appsec-1057-how-to-add-variables-or-blocks-to-the-white-list-tables/87897) & https://www.pinpointdesigns.co.uk/blog/magento-ce-patch-supee-6788-custom-blocks-issue/
- **Magento SUPEE-6788 Developer Toolbox** - find and automatically resolve major problems from the patch
  https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox
- **MageDownload CLI - A PHP tool to automate Magento release and patch downloads** - https://github.com/steverobbins/magedownload-cli
- **How to whitelist template variables and blocks for SUPEE-6788** - https://gist.github.com/avoelkl/f99e95c8caad700aee9
- **Check Magento files for known appsec affected code** - https://github.com/Schrank/magento-appsec-file-check
- **Common issues with SUPEE 6788 Magento patch installation** - http://www.atwix.com/magento/security-patch-supee-6788-installation-issues/
- **Performance improvement for Magento Patch SUPEE-6788** - https://github.com/EcomDev/SUPEE6788-PerformanceFix , https://gist.github.com/DimaSoroka/a3e567ddc39bd6a39c4e , Details - http://www.magecore.com/blog/news/performance-issues-magento-security-patch-supee-6788

Comment: For any "won't fix" modules, can we document what in general needs to be changed so that these modules can be manually patched to work with 6788? For instance, "remove X from all `addFieldToFilter` calls."

Comment: The patch has been released. Please update your answer.

Comment: @FireBear I have already applied Magento patches in past many times.  But I have a doubt about SUPEE-6788.  Do I need to apply it like other patches and later I can enable admin routing capability in Magento admin panel or while installation time only I have to take care.  Please suggest.

Comment: @Muk yes you can install it as other patches, but need to beware about broken extensions, if you use some extensions form the list - you need to fix them manually or wait for update from developers, until that you can enable - Admin routing capability for extensions

Comment: @FireBear Could you provide your feedback on https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/quot-Before-quot-and-quot-After-quot-in-admin-router-SUPEE-6788/m-p/20201#M1363  (Before and After in custom module)

Comment: @Muk i think this question answered and explained on patch notes with details - because of security :)

Answer (score 21):

Along the lines of other comments about detecting conflicts, we at ParadoxLabs have created a script to track down everything affected by APPSEC-1034 (admin controllers) and APPSEC-1057 (whitelist). It will also attempt to fix any bad controllers, since that's a fairly precise and invasive change to make.

It doesn't cover APPSEC-1063 (SQL injection) or APPSEC-1079 (custom options), but it would be great if it could. Not sure how to detect those with any sort of precision. We're open to contributions.

https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox

Comment: this looks really useful, good work!

Comment: fixWhitelists adds blocks to whitelists but doesn't seem to do the same for variables - please could you confirm?

Comment: @zigojacko It covers both.

Comment: Yep, figured this out by giving it a go. Excellent work, super job by ParadoxLabs :)

Comment: Respect to ParadoxLabs. That tool is saving a big amount of work.

Comment: superb,,,+1 from me....saves a lot of time.....:-)

Answer (score 5):

This php script might be useful in identifying Magento code affected by the proposed [SUPEE-6788 patch](https://info2.magento.com/rs/318-XBX-392/images/SUPEE-6788-Technical%20Details.pdf).

**This is in no way a foolproof security check** for this patch, but might be useful to quickly scan your installation for the modules and code affected.

Install the script with

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gaiterjones/magento-appsec-file-check/master/magento_appsec_file_check.php
```

edit the path to your Magento installation

```
$_magentoPath='/home/www/magento/';
```

run

```
php magento_appsec_file_check.php
```

Affected files will be displayed:

```
*** Magento security file check ***
[1] APPSEC-1034, addressing bypassing custom admin URL
2 effected files :
<use>admin</use> found in  app/code/community/Itabs/Debit/etc/config.xml
<use>admin</use> found in  app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml


[2] APPSEC-1063, addressing possible SQL injection
2 effected files :
collection->addFieldToFilter(' found in  app/code/community/Itabs/Debit/Model/Export/Abstract.php
collection->addFieldToFilter(' found in  app/code/community/Itabs/Debit/controllers/Adminhtml/OrderController.php
collection->addFieldToFilter(' not found.
collection->addFieldToFilter('\` not found.
collection->addFieldToFilter('\` not found.


[3] APPSEC-1057, template processing method allows access to private information
{{config path= not found.
{{block type= not found.


***********************************
```

The script use grep to search Magento files for occurrences of the code that
may possibly break backward compatibility with customizations or extensions when SUPEE-6788 is applied.

Answer (score 4):

There is already a big list available with all the extensions that will break with SUPEE-6788

More info here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHJL6D6xm3vD349DJsDF88FBI_6PZvx_u3FioC_1-rg/edit#gid=0

Comment: I am really curious to know how this list was collected.

Comment: It was crowdsourced; original source is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHJL6D6xm3vD349DJsDF88FBI_6PZvx_u3FioC_1-rg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please remove the list from the above page and link to the source instead, which is kept up-to-date: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LHJL6D6xm3vD349DJsDF88FBI_6PZvx_u3FioC_1-rg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Is there any contact to let know about updated versions? I see there at least 2-3 modules that were already updated.

Answer (score -1):

The list of allowed variables, that can be processed via content filter, is bigger than was shown in the PDF:

```
+ trans_email/ident_support/name
+ trans_email/ident_support/email
web/unsecure/base_url
web/secure/base_url
trans_email/ident_general/name
+ trans_email/ident_general/email
trans_email/ident_sales/name
trans_email/ident_sales/email
trans_email/ident_custom1/name
trans_email/ident_custom1/email
trans_email/ident_custom2/name
trans_email/ident_custom2/email
general/store_information/name
general/store_information/phone
general/store_information/address
```

(I have added an `+` before the variables that were not described in the PDF)

The allowed blocks that can be processed via content filter are:

```
core/template
catalog/product_new
```