# How to find the list of blocks that must be added to white list after patch 6788 is applied

Tags: patches, cms-block, magento-1.9.2.0

In our multi store magento we have many blocks which some are disabled. Is there any way that provides the list of blocks which need to be added to white list instead of going through all cms blocks one by one?

Answer (score 2):

Please find [How to check which modules are affected by security patch SUPEE-6788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87214/how-to-check-which-modules-are-affected-by-security-patch-supee-6788) and check the introduced community tools. I used https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons to get a list of used block vars. Use `n98-magerun dev:template-var` to get the needed list.

Another approach is https://github.com/rhoerr/supee-6788-toolbox. It is a shell script to search all used block vars.

Comment: Actually I tried the magento_appsec_file_check.php, but it prints in ...,app/design/frontend*  affected file 0. It did not provide any list of cms block. The thing is that if I disable the cache everything works well but with cache enabled only header and footer appears.

Comment: where exactly should I create .n98-magerun/modules?