# Can't login admin page after upgrade from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9

Can't login admin page after upgrade from 1.9.2.1 to 1.9.2.2
After entering address: "index.php/admin" redirects me to default 404 error store page.
I cleaned Magento Cache and browser. Redirects work properly on all web pages of store. It does not work only "admin"
Please help solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Magento 1.9.2.2** included **supee-6788 patche** in this version in order to improve magento security  purpose.

In this version,magento have change url pattern for custom module which are used at admin.

see detail at

https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details

[How to check which modules are affected by security patch SUPEE-6788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87214/how-to-check-which-modules-are-affected-by-security-patch-supee-6788)

As per as,my concept may custom route is created issue ,you need change it procees.
**For example the following config.xml file for a module:**

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <custom_module>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>custom_module</module>
                <frontName>custom_module</frontName>
            </args>
        </custom_module>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

**Should be changed to:**

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <custom_module after="Mage_Adminhtml">CustomModule_Adminhtml</custom_module>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```