# Magento : 6788 patch applied but magereport not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-6788

I installed 6788 patch to my 1.9.0.1 magento site.It is installed succesfully but magereport showing as "not installed".

I think iam using custom theme, so that it is not showing? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes Mage Report does not pick up on this patch, please check the following as stated on their website:

[Patch 6788 is installed but MageReport disagrees?](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-magento-patch-supee-6788/#Patch_6788_is_installed_but_MageReport_disagrees)

- When compilation is enabled in the backend of your Magento,
  SUPEE-6482 doesn’t work properly. Disable compilation (navigate to
  System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button) to
  make sure the patch works. After disabling compilation, check your
  site with magereport.com again. If the check still comes out as not
  installed, try re-compiling.
- Check if the patch is installed in the    correct directory;
- Reload your opcode cache, webserver, php-fpm    process and possible
  other caches. The old code might be still be    active; Check your
  shops’ .htaccess. If you’ve made any adjustements    in your
  .htaccess, it’s possible the patch is only partially    installed;
- Using a Magento version older them Magento 1.6.1.0? Update    to a
  more recent version. When patching Magento versions older then
  Magento 1.6.1.0, certain redirects aren’t added.

You can also see on this page they give you step by step instructions on installation so I would maybe revert your patch and try again following those to see if maybe you did something wrong.

**UPDATE:**

If you have a custom theme here are some files to check:

- Check if your theme has a custom
  template/customer/form/register.phtml or custom
  template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml. If this is the
  case, make sure that it includes a form_key.
- Check if your theme has a custom layout/customer.xml. If this is the case, make sure to apply the necessary changes from the patch (customer_account_resetpassword has been changed to customer_account_changeforgotten).

You can also refer to this SE link for help: [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87214/how-to-check-which-modules-are-affected-by-security-patch-supee-6788)

Comment: I checked all these items but its not working

Comment: my doubt is iam using custom theme, so patch code was not modified in custom theme files.Shall i add code manually to that files?

Comment: Edited my response.

Comment: need  to change resetforgottenpassword.phtml file ? also @Kiwis

Comment: Yes that file is changed in the patch, to see a full list of files changed click here and click "+ expand source" - https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-6788-without-ssh/

Comment: I followed this but no result

Comment: Did you get any errors when applying the patch? Try this checker as your patch may have applied fine and Mage Report is just not picking it up for some reason https://magentary.com/magento-security-patch-tester/

Comment: Take a look at these: https://magentary.com/kb/magento-registration-form-does-not-work-after-supee-6788/  AND  https://magentary.com/kb/reset-password-blank-page-after-supee-6788/  make sure your custom theme has these amends in place.